# Use of Undeclared Identifier when Using two cpp files

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++, and so I am still unclear on how files get linked together and such. I'm doing an exercise in which I have a testing file, bob_test.cpp, the beginning of which is as follows:

```
#include "bob.h"
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(stating_something)
{
    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL("Whatever.", bob::hey("Tom-ay-to, tom-aaaah-to."));
}
```

In the exercise, it's up to me to write "bob.cpp," so my question is this, how do I write it so that it's recognized by the test file? Currently I get a "Use of Undeclared Identifier 'bob'" on that second to last line. I'm using Xcode and I have a bob.cpp and bob.h, nearly empty.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any class named `bob` into `bob.h` having a method called `hey`?

Comment: or a namespace named `bob` in which a free method named `hey` exists

Comment: It doesn't need to be _"recognized"_ by `bob_test.cpp`. Including the  corresponding header is sufficient. You just need to ensure, that `bob.cpp` is linked with your final executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see something like

```
bob::hey("Tom-ay-to, tom-aaaah-to.")
```

`bob` must be either a namespace or class, declared in `bob.h`. The file could be called anything - it doesn't have to match what's on the left of the scope resolution operator `::`.

You'll have to have something somewhere else (probably in `bob.h`) that looks like this:

```
class bob
{
public:
    static std::string hey(const std::string &s);
}
```

or, slightly less likely,

```
namespace bob
{
   std::string hey(const std::string &s);
}
```

This is included in `bob_test.cpp` (by your `#include "bob.h"`) preprocessor directive.

```
/// bob.cpp
#include "bob.h"
#include <string>

std::string bob::hey(const std::string &s)
{
   return "asdfasdfasdf";
}
```

Headers, like `bob.h`, contain what is basically an interface definition (though they may contain implementations, as well - that's another discussion). The statement

```
#include "bob.h"
```

Tells the compiler that, during compilation, it should open `bob.h`, literally paste the contents of that file in place of the `#include` directive, then compile the `.cpp` as if you had placed the contents of the header in the cpp yourself.

If you're attempting to teach this stuff to yourself, congrats and stick with it!

If this is homework, I'd recommend that you go to office hours, grab a white board, and pepper your teacher with questions until it's clear. It's the faculty's job to make this stuff as clear and approachable as possible. (I teach - making things clear isn't always easy, and I welcome questions from my students. Ultimately, I want all of my students to understand and love what they do.)

Comment: Thank you! It's for a service that sends out exercises and then critiques your code.